# Writing a Thank you card

Tags: грамматика

My babushka and diedushka gave me money for Christmas, and I want to write a thank you card to them. I am pretty comfortable with Russian, but how would I start the letter? And how would I end it? Also, if I say "Thanks for all the money", is that ,"Спасиво за все деньги" или "Спасибо за всех денег"? And one last thing: they recently introduced me to a new " Russian buddy" and I wanted to thank them for that as well. I would I say, "Thank you for introducing me to Igor!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can keep it simple, start by *Дорогие дeдушка Ваня и бабушка Аня* (substitute names though), end by *ваш внук [your name here]*. It's better to thank them for the gift, not the money (even if they gave you the money), so you could say *спасибо за ваш щедрый подарок.*
To thank for the introduction: *спасибо, что познакомили меня с Игорем, [он очень интересный человек]*. Or *хочу поблагодарить вас за то, что ...*

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

> Спасибо вам за деньги.

About "Russian buddy" Igor:

> Спасибо, что познакомили меня с Игорем.